# Is it possible to change productName via xcconfig file in xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, config

I am setting below two parameters in **Config.xcconfig** file to fetch `appDisplayName` and `bundle Identifier` from config file. I did my code in xcconfig file as :

```
appDisplayName=myapp
appIdentifier=org.prince.myapp
```

Set in app-**Info.plist** file as

```
Bundle identifier = ${appIdentifier}
Bundle display name =${appDisplayName}
```

add it to project under configurations.

It is working fine as I have given myapp as display name it is showing in simulator/device as it is.

Lets come to the point. I want to know Is there any way to change `PRODUCT_NAME` variable value.  I set  `PRODUCT_NAME=custom`  in configuration file but this doesn't seems to work.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O yes, I have done it...

set PRODUCT_NAME=kat in Config.xcconfig file and place PRODUCT_NAME variable on

->Targets --> Build Setting -->Packaging --> Product Name  as given below in screenshot

[image]

Answer (score -2):

[image: See this image]

From here you can edit Bundle display name, bundle name. Double click on $[PRODUCT_NAME] then you will able to edit this.

If you want to changes PRODUCT_NAME for Localization, means if you want to change product name in different language according to device language then you can localize InfoPlist.strings file and add following in all language file -

```
    "CFBundleDisplayName" = "Your_Product_Name"; 
    "CFBundleName" = "Your_Product_Name";
```

Comment: I want to change the value of PRODUCT_NAME variable value

Comment: @trup, although your answer is a good one if someone asked how to change the product name in xcode, it is not the answer the the above question where hercules is asking how to do it programmically in config.xcconfig. Try improving your answer.